# renderMapImageInBoundingBox doesn't do anything on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I have a UITableView where each cell should display a map. As it's a known limitation to have several independent instances of SKMapView in one view (see http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec29) and I don't want a SKMapView in each cell anyway (performance) I thought I'd use renderMapImageInBoundingBox and create an image of the map to display in the tableCells.

I've tried several things and stripped down the code to just render an image for the first map. This is a stripped down versions of what I have in my UITableViewController's viewDidAppear (I also tried viewDidLoad, but nothing).

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    //Initialize, set delegate, and customize map appearance
    var mapView = SKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 963, 200))
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.applySettingsFromFileAtPath(JSONFilePath)
    mapView.mapScaleView.hidden = true
    mapView.settings.showAccuracyCircle = false
    mapView.settings.panningEnabled = false
    mapView.settings.rotationEnabled = false
    mapView.settings.showStreetBadges = false
    mapView.settings.showHouseNumbers = false
    mapView.settings.showMapPoiIcons = false
    mapView.settings.showOneWays = false

    //Draw a track on the map
    let track = tracks[0]
    var polyline = SKPolyline()
    polyline.coordinates = track.points
    polyline.fillColor = themeTintColor
    polyline.lineWidth = 3
    polyline.backgroundLineWidth = 4
    polyline.borderDotsSize = 1
    polyline.borderDotsSpacingSize = 5
    mapView.addPolyline(polyline)

    //Set BoundingBox        
    let boundingBox = SKBoundingBox(topLeftCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(track.ne.coordinate.latitude, track.sw.coordinate.longitude), bottomRightCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(track.sw.coordinate.latitude, track.ne.coordinate.longitude))

    // Add the mapView to the view just to see if it displays correctly. (It does!)
    mapView.fitBounds(boundingBox, withPadding: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)

    // Actual PNG rendering
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    mapView.renderMapImageInBoundingBox(boundingBox, toPath: documentsPath, withSize: CGSizeMake(1000, 220))
    println("Rendering in progress")
}


func mapViewDidFinishRenderingImageInBoundingBox(mapView: SKMapView!) {
    println("ImageRenderingFinished")
}
```

The mapView is displayed correctly (with correct bounding box) and in the log I see the "Rendering in progress" message, but mapViewDidFinishRenderingImageInBoundingBox is not being called and I don't see a png file created in my App Container. No compiler or run-time errors. (btw I did not forget to add the SKMapViewDelegate)

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Or did I run into a bug?
Using Xcode 6.1, developing for iOS8 in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this. I made a VERY VERY stupid mistake. 
I gave the documentsPath as a parameter to the function, which is a directory, but the function needs a full path, including filename.

This made it work:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let imagePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("images/mapImage.png")
mapView.renderMapImageInBoundingBox(boundingBox, toPath: imagePath, withSize: CGSizeMake(1000, 220))
```

I should drink more coffee!